# i want to initial display all the date from the api then display it based on the search bar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zxrN.png)

```
 {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}{" "}
          {news.map((item: Iitem, id) => {
            return (
              <Box mt={"20px"} key={id}>
                <NewsCard
                  title={item.headline}
                  description={item.description}
                  url={item.url}
                  image={item.promoImage.url}
                  author={item.authorFormatted}
                  date={item.shortDateLastPublished}
                  tag={item.section.tagName}
                />
              </Box>
            );
          })}
```

i tried conditional rendering  but it is not working and it keep rerednering i have removed the url for privacy *

Comment: In what way is the code shown not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: It seems like your question lacks clarity and specific details, making it difficult for us to provide an accurate solution. For example, a search bar is mentioned, however, there is no further elaboration.